# How do I foreach a json list in php using curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I am wondering how I would list the json values for each part of the list

my php code

```
$uri = "https://yt-dl-server.herokuapp.com/api/info?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$id";

$ci = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ci, CURLOPT_URL, $uri );
curl_setopt( $ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$channelOBJE = json_decode( curl_exec( $ci ) );

$format_note = $channelOBJE->info->formats[20]->format_note; 
$videourl = $channelOBJE->info->formats[20]->url; 
$audiourl = $channelOBJE->info->formats[1]->url; 
echo $format_note;
echo "<br>";
```

Following that code I want to get the $format_note for every formats[] but I don't want to have to list the number value of it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with looping on `$channelOBJE->info`?

Comment: You should try to be clearer in  your terminology and question; neither the JSON data format nor PHP natively have the concept of lists. cURL is for making remote requests to send or receive data, it doesn't have the concept of foreach. It's unclear whether you are trying to iterate over multiple results from a single cURL request or whether you want to avoid needing to make multiple requests to obtain all the data you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through array of multiple arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528481/how-to-loop-through-array-of-multiple-arrays-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use foreach() to loop the formats.

```
foreach($channelOBJE->info->formats as $format){
    var_dump($format->format_note);
}
```